# What is the advantage of using angular with electronJS

Tags: electron, angular7

I want to create desktop application compatible with other OS.For that I'm using electron with angular.Because both are frame work whether it will effect performance or loading time, and also whether deploying easy,can we use all the features of angular when we use with electron like routing..?

Answer (score 0):

Electron uses Chromium and NodeJS which is the reason why it is compatible with other OSs. You can talk with the NodeJS process from your angular-app which opens up some possibilities. For example opening native file-dialogs to let the user choose files. Electron also already abstracts some platform specific operations like getting the user home to save some configuration files for example.

You can use routing just like in any Angular app and I think you can use most features like you would normally but dont take me for granted on this one.

I would not say it affects your loading time to combine those too. During development you have to build your angular app before electron can start up and use those files but in production Angular is already ready to be loaded so they dont hinder each other.